# No such module Error "NotificationCenter" WatchOS, Swift

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos

I'm getting an module error in two of my controllers who tries to import the NotificationCenter framework. I have added the framework in "linked frameworks and libraries" but I'm still getting the error.

I even tried `cmd + shift + k`, but it did not do any good for me.

I also tried to set the framework search path to $(SRCROOT), but still same error.

I have two controllers with the import.

[Linked frameworks and libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b82TG.jpg)

[Added notificationCenter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iohkc.jpg)

**TimeController**

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import NotificationCenter   error: "No such module 'NotificationCenter'"
```

**SwipeController**

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import NotificationCenter   error: "No such module 'NotificationCenter'"
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: No its called NotificationCenter, added a screenshot :)

Comment: Is that your WatchKit Extension target the screenshot is from?

Comment: Its from projects settings in the general tab

Comment: But which target? There are at least 3 targets in a watchOS project, the iOS target, WatchKit App target and WatchKit Extension target. You need to link the framework to your WatchKit Extension target to be able to access it from your watchOS classes

Comment: Do you mean here? see added screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @David's comment, There are three targets for a single watchOS project.

**You need to try these steps for each Target:** 
Select each target and go to -> Build Phases

[image: Screen1]

Click on the ***right arrow***. and click on the ***+***
[image: Step2]

Finally, search for ***NotificationCenter*** and add the framework.

You need to try these steps for each target.

[image: Watch]

Comment: it is added there, see new screenshot :)

Comment: @Thosc, for each one?

Comment: That's target dependencies, not *Link binary with Libraries*

Comment: see new screenshot :))

Comment: again, That's *target dependencies*, not *Link binary with Libraries*